# Can I use Firebase on a fragment in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a **Contact form** for my android application.The contact information should get stored in my **Firebase**
The contact form exists in a **fragment**(I am not sure that this is the problem).
the code I use:

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

    private Firebase Ref;
    private EditText name,lastname,phone,email;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);// Inflate the layout for this fragment


        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        lastname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        phone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Ref = new Firebase("my-url-goes-here");





        return view;
    }


    public void save(View view) {
        String nameinput = name.getText().toString();
        String lastnameinput = lastname.getText().toString();
        String phoneinput = phone.getText().toString();
        String emailinput = email.getText().toString();
        Firebase Rname = Ref.child("name");
        Rname.seValue(nameinput);
        Firebase Rlastname = Ref.child("lastname");
        Rlastname.setValue(lastnameinput);
        Firebase Rphone = Ref.child("phone");
        Rphone.setValue(phoneinput);
        Firebase Remail = Ref.child("email");
        Remail.setValue("email");





    }



}
```

Everything seems to be good except the `Firebase` and the `setValue()` is red.
When I try to build the app I get this Error message

```
error: cannot find symbol
    private Firebase Ref;
            ^
  symbol:   class Firebase
  location: class ContactFragment
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a fragment/activity. What's the error message that you get? Add the error stack trace in the question itself.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot the error message I edited in

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo It doesnt show up on the logtrace because the app wont even start to build because of the error above

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the Firebase Realtime Database APIs correctly at all.  You might be using a very old version of the Firebase SDK.  I suggest starting over and using the documentation to add the SDK.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: Ok i will try that thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should do the next

1. In your application activity should call the instance before your aplicaction starts

   package com.prueba.analytics

   import android.app.Application
   import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
   import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics

   fun Application.setupFireBase() {
       fireBaseDatabase = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)!!
       firebaseTracker = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
   }

   package com.prueba

   import android.app.Application
   import com.prueba.analytics.setupFireBase

   class PruebaApplication : Application() {
       override fun onCreate() {
           super.onCreate()
           setupFireBase()
       }
   }
2. You should have the google-services.json and google-services's library

   [image]

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Comment: Hello thanks for the quick reply!
Do i put your code on java file of my fragment?